# Vimeo Pro Player - make custom logo link to site, or add link icon?

Tags: vimeo-player

I am considering upgrading to a Vimeo Pro account in order to customize the video player. I see that you can upload your own logo, but I want to make sure that you can set the logo to link to a url of your choice.

If not through the logo, is there a way to add a custom icon that will provide such a link?

Finally, if not through either of the above, is such functionality available through the "3rd party players"? I can't find any info on 3rd party players.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the logo link to any URL.

Under the videos go to `Embed` then check `Use Custom Logo`, you can then check `Link this logo to` and enter your desired URL.